# Poco: Is it possible to do signal handling the same way it's done with libuv and Boost::Asio?

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I'm implementing a server using Poco and I saw there's references to Events and signals, but I don't think these refer to signals sent by the operating system. So, is it possible to handle specific OS signals with POCO or should I delegate that work to an external library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but seems like it: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SignalHandler.html

Answer (score 2):

Events and Signals are used for communication between objects(similar to delegates/events system of .net and signals/slots of QT) and are feature-rich implementation of consumer/producer design pattern. 
If you're interested in handling POSIX signals like SIGILL, SIGSEGV, etc. [Poco::SignalHandler](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SignalHandler.html) is what you're looking for. It translates OS signals to exceptions.